# Unable to import a module from a module in a different package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

My project is set-up as follows:

project
- concrete_classes
-- test_module.py
- unit_tests
-- unit_tests_test_module.py
- main.py

In main.py I can go "from concrete_classes import test_module"
In unit_tests_test_module.py I can't go "from concrete_classes import test_module" (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'concrete_classes'). Same issue if I try "import concrete_classes.test_module"

I am using this guide as a reference: https://www.internalpointers.com/post/modules-and-packages-create-python-project, namely the "Importing modules from above" section and it seems like I'm doing exactly as they do.

Where am I going wrong?

Some searching tells me it might be an issue with my system path but I'm not sure what I'm expecting to see when I look at my sys.path

Comment: Try `from concrete_classes.test_module import test_module`. That should be the way if you are working with classes.

Comment: maybe it is because concrete_classes should be a package? For that you can create a blank file named __init__.py in concrete_classes

Comment: @Manuel Doing that gives me a yellow squiggly saying "unresolved import 'concrete_classes.test_module'" and running it still gives "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'concrete_classes'"

Comment: @rolf82 My understanding is I don't need to make an __init__.py above Python 3.2. But adding one makes no difference

Comment: Nice to have tried anyway just in case. I reproduced you problem, and the only thing I can see is adding your project's dir to your PYTHONPATH shell variable. I tried it and it worked, and I don't think you can avoid that, because python needs to know where to search.

Comment: @rofl82 Thanks so much! That did the trick. Seems like it was a pathing problem after all

Answer (score 0):

One solution I always use is to add your project root directory to your system path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/project")
```

Then you can safely import all the submodules.

Comment: sys.path.append("C:/Users/me/Documents/project") didn't make a difference. And if they did, wouldn't that make for annoying set-up (and clean-up) every time someone copies the project to their computer, moves the project location or renames the folder?

Comment: @AdamVengroff Have you added `__init__.py` to all the folders? Without that, you won't be able to import.

Comment: My understanding is that I don't need to do that since I'm above Python 3.2. I tried adding __init__.py to all folders but no luck.